# Docker, Visual Studio 2019 and shared folders

Tags: docker, dockerfile, visual-studio-2019

If you could share your experience with dockers and this particle problem ...

We made new API solution using Visual Studio 2019 community version, with Docker for Linux. After installing `Docker for Desktop` and adding `Dockerfile` to solution, API is being run successfully and we have a response from API hosted in a docker and that is working perfectly (from debug in local).

But idea in this solution is that user copy some type of XML file in a folder that also a docker container it self can access ... and here is the moment where we can't figure it out.

So here is the thing ... we figured out how to share volume to a container, with use of

```
docker run -t -d -v {Path}:{To}:{Folder}:/{Destination}/{Path} --name {container_name} {image_name}:{image_tag_name}
```

With use of above command, we create new container and once we do

```
docker inspect {container_name}
```

Here we can see that share folder is really in "Mounted" part and if we inspect it using terminal we can see all files in there

But there lies the problem ...

We can create new container with shared folder (`manually typing code in cmd`)

We can run container with use of Visual Studio 2019 (`as VS creates container for solution itself`)

But how can we mix these two, do we need to modify and how can we modify container that is being used in our solution? How to actually share folder with that specific container?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following property to your .csproj file:

```
<DockerfileRunArguments>-v {HostPath}:{ContainerPath}</DockerfileRunArguments>
```

This will be added to the "docker run" command that Visual Studio uses to start the container.